# Tracking the fields in view

Tags: views, entities

How to track the content fields changes in view, just like history review.

When we click on that particular field of content, my aim is some how to track the field of content type have gone through field track changes module. But its of no luck.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30768/discussion-between-kashish-and-huelfe) conversation.

Answer (score 0):

Using the track_field_changes module, I was able to get the side by side values in a view. Note , I also have revisions turned on for this node type.

Comment: I have seen this and read the above conversation it gives the multiple rows of same field and side by value it provides....but I want it at a shot for single field need to see history

Comment: where exactly u have turned on the revision for the node type

Comment: revision is turned on by default, if I am not wrong

Comment: apart from this do we have any other options to track the field history because in the view it inserts multiple rows for same node if edit the specified field.

Answer (score 0):

Considering your scenario you can set 'Number of values' property of field to multiple and its also easy to handle in view. But if you do so, remember to fetch latest value from the field.

Here you go:

- Admin » Structure » Content types » Your Content type » Manage fields » Edit Your field
- Set 'Number of values' property to multiple. i.e. suppose you want to track 10 time values changed in history.

Now when you use this field in view:

- Edit your view and add this field
- In setting of this field you'll find 'MULTIPLE FIELD SETTINGS'
- Here select the checkbox 'Reversed' i.e. start from last values.

This will work as history to your field.

[image: See the in result all the values added to field in reverse order, i. e. latest first.]

[image: I've added one node on which i'm adding 3 values in token field.]

Comment: :can u tell me in stepwise so that I can understand clearly...

Comment: I've updated answer. I hope this will work for you.:)

Comment: I followed the steps what u mentioned the result is same as before no change at all. for specific node it displaying only current corresponding value....but history of that corresponding field value I could not see

Comment: please check the screen shot where in though I followed I am unable to get history

Comment: where exactly u clicking to see the history of field  after all this settings

Comment: Please add some multiple values in fileds on nodes and check in views

Comment: I understood yes it gives the all values if we select multiple data at once : but here in my case only one data whenever edit n save, next time while editing the same content we may change the same field data into other field data ....which means  I want to see what data has been saved before this existing one for same field

Comment: Look at the last image i've uploaded. whenever you edit the node you add extra value to that field. Don't replace the existing value.

Comment: ohhhhhh this field is not simple text field its multiselect field.... consist of only 4 select list values):

Comment: It is simple text field. At very beginning I've mentioned it that edit your field and set 'Number of values' property to multiple, say unlimited or just 10.

Comment: not your field .....the one field for which I want to track the history......for simple field as u said I am getting the out put....but problem with my field because I want to track for select list field....mine is not simple text field its select list field.

Comment: Ohh.. So in that case i'd like to suggest you that store that selected value in simple text box if possible with custom code. this will help you to keep track. hook_node_submit() may helpful in this case.

Comment: I understand.....actually I am very new to coding n drupal its toughie for me......well is there any other way or module available to achieve this?